# Pass foreach data into modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a foreach that displays data. each item has a online and offline status. with ajax I let the user activate and deactivate using:

```
$active = '<a id="status'.$restaurant->restaurant_id.'" class="btn btn-bricky" href="#" onclick="return changeRestStatus(\''.$restaurant->restaurant_id.'\',\'changeActive\');"><i id="status'.$restaurant->restaurant_id.'icon" class="fa fa-times fa fa-white"></i></a>';
```

This is a button that triggers a Javascript method. In this method there is a ajax call (i have shortend the code:

Javascript:

```
function changeRestStatus(restaurantID,type) {
    if (type == 'changeActive') {

        //ChangeStatus
        $.post("adminAjaxFile.php", 
        { 
            'restaurantID':restaurantID,
            'action':type 
        },
        function(response){
            if(response == "activated"){

                //change the button...
                $("#status"+ restaurantID).removeClass('btn-bricky');
            $("#status"+ restaurantID).addClass('btn-green');
                $("#status"+ restaurantID +"icon").removeClass('fa fa-times fa fa-white');
            $("#status"+ restaurantID +"icon").addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign');
                return false;

            }
            if(response == "deactivated"){

                //change the button...
                $("#status"+ restaurantID).removeClass('btn-green');
            $("#status"+ restaurantID).addClass('btn-bricky');
                $("#status"+ restaurantID +"icon").removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign');
            $("#status"+ restaurantID +"icon").addClass('fa fa-times fa fa-white');

                return false;

            }
            else if (response == "noaccess") {
                //show error
                return false;

            } 
            else {
                alert(response);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

}
```

All works well but, now I need some text input before this button is clicked (call is executed)

So now I want a link that opens a modal with a input field. After this is filled it sends the data to the same method (like $active var) but then with a extra parameter that holds the input.

But i dont know how to approach this. I could put the modal in the foreach so for every row a new modal gets created with the proper data but this seems rubbish.

So how to i make a button that opens a modal and sends these vars to this modal, so i can send it further to the ChangeRestStatus method.

(im using some template for the modals.. its made with bootstrap) here it is:

```
<!-- MODAL -->
<div id="responsive" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            &times;
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Responsive</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h4>Some Input</h4>
                <p>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-light-grey">
            Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">
            OK
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END: MODAL -->

<!-- Link that triggers modal -->
<a href="#responsive" data-toggle="modal" class="demo btn btn-blue">
    Open modal
</a>
```

EDIT:

So the best way is to add: $('#responsive').modal(); in to the method. The problem is that i need it to get the input from the modal, when user clicks OK and then take the data and go further with the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i got it working, dont know if its a nice solution but it works.

- Added a if else statement to check if the button has a certain class. If it has a green class then a modal with a text input is needed. Else no modal needed. here is the code (feedback would be nice)
- When modal is needed, theres a click function that checks if submit is clicked

the actual code is much bigger but mostly with look things. so i have removed that.. just to show the solution

```
    //CHANGE ONLINE OFFLINE
    function changeOnlineStatus(restaurantID,type) {

    if (type == 'changeOnlineGetInput') {
        //Check if status is online -> Modal (reason) needed
        if ($("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID).hasClass('btn-green')) {
            //Modal
            $('#responsive').modal();
            $('#confirmOnline').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

                    //AJAX START
                    var type = 'changeOnline';
                    var reason = $('#reason').val();
                    $.post("adminAjaxFile.php", 
                    { 
                        'reason':reason,
                        'restaurantID':restaurantID,
                        'action':type 
                    },
                    function(response){
                        if(response == "online"){

                            //change the button...
                            $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID).removeClass('btn-bricky');
                        $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID).addClass('btn-green');
                            $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID +"icon").removeClass('fa fa-times fa fa-white');
                        $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID +"icon").addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign');
                            return false;

                        }
                        if(response == "offline"){

                            //change the button...
                            $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID).removeClass('btn-green');
                        $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID).addClass('btn-bricky');
                            $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID +"icon").removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign');
                        $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID +"icon").addClass('fa fa-times fa fa-white');
                            return false;

                        }
                        else if (response == "noaccess") {
                            //do something
                            return false;

                        } 
                        else {
                            alert(response);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    //return false;

                //Hide modal
                $('#responsive').modal('hide');
                return false;
                });
        }
        //No modal needed just put online
        else {
                    var type = 'changeOnline';
                    $.post("adminAjaxFile.php", 
                    { 
                        'restaurantID':restaurantID,
                        'action':type 
                    },
                    function(response){
                        if(response == "online"){

                            //change the button...
                            $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID).removeClass('btn-bricky');
                        $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID).addClass('btn-green');
                            $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID +"icon").removeClass('fa fa-times fa fa-white');
                        $("#statusOnlineOffline"+ restaurantID +"icon").addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign');
                            return false;

                        }
                        if(response == "offline"){
                            //do something
                            return false;

                        }
                        else if (response == "noaccess") {
                            //do something
                            return false;

                        } 
                        else {
                            alert(response);
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    //return false;
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work proper. When setting multiple items from offline to online it works. But when you put those items to offline again, it only works for 1 item. when you change a second item it changes mutiple values to offline?